# Full calendar- highlight row and column on mouse hover cell

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I'm using full calendar and I want to highlight (or somehow change the color) of the row and column when the cursor is over a cell. Till now I have been able to highlight the row through this css:

```
.fc-content td:hover{
        background: #DBDBDB; 
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
```

Now this is the view:
[image]

As you can see the raw of the cell which I refer to is darker. I want to do the same thing for the column.

If possible, I want also to highlight the resource raw (it can be seen that is not highlighted).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this article will help you: https://css-tricks.com/simple-css-row-column-highlighting/

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm stuck on this as well...

Comment: @rubberchicken It has been 2 years since then, but I solved by editing the core files of fullcalendar. The idea is to add a class to each column and row header, and then to use JQuery to listen for mouse position. I remember that I also asked this question which is related to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36130099/3944251