# Jquery -event: mouse X position is within element's vertical borders range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to handle the event when mouse X position is within a class's vertical borders range. I mean, if the element's X position is:

```
X: 200px;
X+element.width(): 500px;
```

I wanna know if the mouse is horizontally within (200px, 500px). It's vertical position doesn't matter. Here it is some further explanation:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted

> I wanna know if the mouse is horizontally within (200px, 500px). It's
>   vertical position doesn't matter.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).on('mousemove', function(e){
    if((e.pageX >= $('#container').offset().left) && (e.pageX <= $('#container').offset().left + $('#container').width())){
        $('#container').addClass('in');
      }
    else
      $('#container').removeClass('in');
  });  

});
```

```css
#container{
  height:50px;
  position:relative;
  margin-left:200px;
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid;
  transition:.2s all;
}

#container.in{
  color:white;
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"> I go black when mouse is within my horizontal limits.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below is quite self-explanatory:

```js
function isWithinBoundries($el, ev) {
  var x = ev.pageX,
      leftBound = $el.offset().left,
      rightBound = leftBound + $el.width();
  
  return (x > leftBound && x < rightBound) ? true : false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $elem = $('.myDiv');
  
  $(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    $elem.html(isWithinBoundries($elem, e) + '');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.myDiv {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">false</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.clientX` or `event.pageX`:

```js
$(document).on('click mousemove', function(e) {
  var msg;
  if (e.pageX <= $('#mydiv').outerWidth(true)) {
    msg = 'within width of mydiv';
  } else {
    msg = 'outside of width of mydiv';
  }
  $('pre').html(msg);
});
```

```css
.mydiv {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
<div id='mydiv' class='mydiv'>My Div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no other possibility than make comparison of coordinates on mousemove event. Something like:

```
$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
    if(event.pageX > $('#myDiv').offset().left && event.pageX < $('#myDiv').offset().left + $('#myDiv').width()) {
        console.log('I am in range! Cursor X pos: ' + event.pageX);
    }
});
```

Console.log is fired every time mouse moves in given range. If you want just detect entering, you can introduce a variable like:

```
var inRange = false;
$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
    if(event.pageX > $('#myDiv').offset().left && event.pageX < $('#myDiv').offset().left + $('#myDiv').width()) {
        if (!inRange) {
            console.log('I am in range! Cursor X pos: ' + event.pageX);
        }
        inRange = true;
    } else {
        inRange = false;
    }
});
```

I hope you find this helpful...

note: I use id selection, so to make it work, you should give an id="myDiv" to your div...

note 2: Of course you can also use a class selector - in code just use '.myDiv' instead of '#myDiv'.

I made a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jankovskyp/0uc9t5tv/).